# js function call with parameter value from <p:commandButton>

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have a code like:

```
<p:commandButton type="submit" value="Select User" onclick="showGrpMemberSearchPageCalenderLeave(#{groupname})"/>
```

Here I have set the value of `groupname` like:

```
<c:set var="groupname" value="#{session.getAttribute('USER_GROUP_NAME')}"/>
```

If I print this value `#{session.getAttribute('USER_GROUP_NAME')}` it gives the correct value. but the java script function that I want to call `showGrpMemberSearchPageCalenderLeave(#{groupname})` is not invoked.

The function is:

```
function showGrpMemberSearchPageCalenderLeave(groupName){
var x= (screen.width-530)/2;
var y= (screen.height-450)/2;
window.open('./SearchGroupMembersLeaveCalander.xhtml?groupName='+groupName,'mywindow','resizable=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,height=450,width=530,top='+y+',left='+x);
return false;
}
```

this actually opens a popup. when I did not have the parameter value, the popup opened fine. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onclick="showGrpMemberSearchPageCalenderLeave(#{groupname})"
```

So, you're printing the EL variable `#{groupname}` as a JS variable? Imagine that `#{groupname}` returns a string value of `somegroup`, then this code get ultimately rendered as follows (open page in browser, rightclick and *View Source* to see it yourself):

```
onclick="showGrpMemberSearchPageCalenderLeave(somegroup)"
```

Do you have a JS variable `somegroup` in the JS scope? Apparently not. It look like that you intented to pass it as a JS string. You should then quote it. You ultimately want that JSF generates the following HTML/JS code:

```
onclick="showGrpMemberSearchPageCalenderLeave('somegroup')"
```

You should then write the JSF/EL code in such way that it generates exactly the desired HTML/JS code:

```
onclick="showGrpMemberSearchPageCalenderLeave('#{groupname}')"
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the value in your `c:set` makes no sense:

```
<c:set var="groupname" value="#{session.getAttribute('USER_GROUP_NAME')}"/>
```

It look like that you do not understand how [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) works. It already searches for variables in page, request, session and application scope. This should be done as follows:

```
<c:set var="groupname" value="#{USER_GROUP_NAME}"/>
```